# Text wrapping when trying to include Object in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a mobile version of my website and I want to use includes on copyright info, menus, etc. - stuff that would be the same from page to page. In the past I've used `SSI`, but my hosting service doesn't support SSI anymore. So now I'm wanting to use `Objects` in this form:

```
<OBJECT data="copyright4.3s.html">
Warning: HTML File could not be included.
</OBJECT>
```

This is working, but I have limited control over how the included html is displayed. For example, I want the included html to be centered on the page, and so I've discovered that I have to create the centering div in the main page and then put the above code in that centering div. Also, I've found that I have to include the text formatting in the header of the included html, otherwise it doesn't see the text formatting if it's referenced from the main page. Now my problem is that the included html text is wrapping, and I want it all on a single line. I can't for the life of me figure out why the text is wrapping. So my main html and the include html are as follows:
Main HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>

<title>Template</title>
<style>
*,
*:before,
*:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
box-sizing:         border-box;
}
body,html {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

/* Page Headline */
.title-headline{
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;

}

.title-headline span {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: normal;
}

.title-headline h2 {
display: block;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.7em;
margin-top: 0.83em;
margin-bottom: 0.83em;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
font-weight: bold;
}
/* END Page Headline */

.mob-p {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:1.3em;
line-height:145%;
padding-right:1.8em;
padding-left:1.8em;
}

/* COPYRIGHT INCLUDE */

copyright-container{
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.copyright-container-div{
width:100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: #ffff99;
}

/* END COPYRIGHT INCLUDE */



/* FOOTER */

footer-container{
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
}
.ad-footer {
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #efefef;
text-align: center;
}
.ad-buffer{
margin-top:30px;
height:70px;
}

.nav-arrows-bottom{
width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
height:50px;
}
.nav-arrows-btm-left{
float:left;
padding:10px;
}

.nav-arrows-btm-right{
float:right;
padding:10px;
}
.nav-arrow-left {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 20px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;

border-right: 20px solid green;
}
.nav-arrow-right {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 20px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
border-left: 20px solid green;
}
.nav-arrows-pad{
width: 100%;
height:1em;
}

/* END FOOTER */

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="body-content">
<div class="title-headline">
<h2>Heading</h2>
</div>
<p class="mob-p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula    eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur    ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla   consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.  In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede     mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate    eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam   lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius    laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper    ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus,  sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel,    luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae   sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus   tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed  consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>  
<img style="float: right; margin: 0px 0px 15px 15px;" src="images/misc/contact_message.png"     width="100" />  
<p class="mob-p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula    eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur    ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla   consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.  In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede     mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate    eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam   lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius    laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper    ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus,  sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel,    luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae   sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus   tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed  consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>  

<hr align="center" width="50%">


<div class="copyright-container-div">
    <OBJECT data="copyright4.3s.html">
    Warning: HTML File could not be included.
    </OBJECT>
</div>

</div>

<footer-container>

<div class="nav-arrows-bottom">
    <div class="nav-arrows-btm-left">
    <div class="nav-arrow-left"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-arrows-btm-right">
    <div class="nav-arrow-right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nav-arrows-pad"></div>

<div class="ad-footer">
    I'm gonna put an ad in this space.
</div>
</footer-container>

</body>
</html>
```

Included HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Copyright</title>
<style>

.copyright-container-inc-div{
width:100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: #ff0000;
}
p.copyright-include{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="copyright-container-inc-div">
<p class="copyright-include">All website content &#169; copyright example.com All Rights    Reserved</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default size of an `object` element is 300 by 150 pixels. This forces wrapping in the content if it needs more than 300 pixels horizontally.

A simple way around this is the the following CSS rule, in the embedding element:

```
object { width: 100%; }
```

This also makes your container element to be as wide as the embedding page and therefore the red background extend over it. If you don’t want this, you need to tune the styling in the embedded page.

Comment: Wow, such a simple fix! And it works, too! I've never used objects in html before, is it common knowledge that the default size of an object element is 300 x 150?

Comment: I thought the default size was specified in HTML5, but it seems that it isn’t; anyway, 300 × 150 is the common browser default for `object` as well as for `iframe`.